# How to access Employee Id from Azure AD using Microsoft graph

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

At first I want to mentioned I did search for the answer but I did not get the concrete answer. So here I am asking again.

I am using ASP.NET MVC project and using Microsoft graph to get information from Azure AD. I am trying to get `EmployeeId` along with `DisplayName`. For the scope I am using `user.readbasic.all`.

With below query I am getting `DiplayName` for all the users but for `EmployeeID` I am getting null. Except for myself.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=DisplayName,EmployeeId
```

When I use "me" then again get the `EmployeeID`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=DisplayName,EmployeeId
```

So using the `user.readbasic.all` I do get employee id but for myself but why not for others

Comment: Hello @Salma, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to for others Employee ID has not been set.

Example:  Employee ID has not been set for a user ,so it is showing null.

[image]
[image]

Let me Set an employee ID for a user.

[image]

Now I am testing for with same API I am getting my EmployeeID value.

[image]

In below Picture you can see as I have set EID for Rahul Only and for others it is showing null.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for looking into it.   I am able to see my empid but not for others.  In case of you, can you try to access employee id for someone else other than yourself.

Comment: Yes I am able to access the employee id of mine and other as well. Just let me clear you employee id will show null if it has no value assigned to it .assign any value and then  try to check.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I check it again. I am getting around 999 records. I can only see employee id o myself but not for anyone else.  I used the user.readbasic.all scope. Also I am not a global admin. I pinpoint other employee and they do have employee id.

Comment: @Salma give User.Read.All modify permission this Allows the app to read the full set of profile properties, reports, and managers of other users in your organization, on your behalf.

Comment: I will do the test after adding the permission for the User.Read.All on portal for the app, but this does require adminstrator consent. Earlier I was testng with the sign-in user not as an admin.

Comment: Yes it require your admin consent. Please contact your admin to give this access and then try. If you are using free trial i am not sure if you can able to access the details of others employees.